# How do I stop RemoteIO when file is finished?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm using the following to play audio:

```
OSStatus PlayRenderCallback (
                              void *                        inRefCon,
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *  ioActionFlags,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *            inTimeStamp,
                              UInt32                            inBusNumber,
                              UInt32                            inNumberFrames,
                              AudioBufferList *             ioData)
{
    EffectState *effectState = (EffectState*) inRefCon;

    if(effectState->play)
    {
        XThrowIfError(ExtAudioFileRead(effectState->sourceFile, &inNumberFrames, ioData), "Read failed!");

        if(inNumberFrames == 0)
        {
            return noErr;
        }
```

Then I process the audio and send it to the buffer.

What I want to know is what do I put in the return to stop playback? I tried:

```
AudioOutputUnitStop(remoteIOUnit);
```

And that works, once. I can't start the unit again.

Thanks all,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot stop a copy of a remote io. Rather than copying I used only the rio in my struct and now it works.